# Strange transparency issue

Tags: html, css, opacity, transparent, squarespace

I'm having a strange transparency issue with my parralax headers.
Check it out:[image: Transparency issue]
As far as i know, the styling of the banner container should be 100% transparent, but it keeps showing a faint edge where the two containers meet.
It happens through out the website [www.bardurm.com](https://www.bardurm.com/visualarts/villmarka)

Do you guys know what causes this? does it have to do with the way the browser displays opacity or something?

any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreachiated

Kind regards
Bardur M

Comment: You need to [edit] and add a repro as a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is very poorly formatted for stackoverflow.  Generally it's discouraged to link to entire sites or external sources of code.  Ideally, you should recreate the problem in a stack snippet as linked by Will; but as soon as you try, you'll realize that the line is due to a simple mistake and there will be no point in updating the question.  That being the case, the solution to your problem is that you have a background color on the `.tweak-overlay-parallax-enabled .Parallax-item` rule.  Remove that and it'll be fixed.  Because this is not really helpful to future ...

Comment: visitors, I recommend closing this question after you have resolved the issue.  It will not likely be beneficial to future visitors experiencing similar issues.

Comment: That or you could set the background color for that rule to be `#1d1f24`

Comment: Remove the `.Parallax-item` on line `893`

Comment: Thanks for the information Joseph, i'll remember that for any future posts.
And thanks for guiding me to the issue guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok

First of all your first div has another color than body

```
.tweak-overlay-parallax-enabled .Parallax-item {
   background-color: #1e2024
}

body {
   background-color:#1d1f23
}
```

Then you apply transparency on the main content div so its going to take body's background color (color behind it).

Here is your options:

**Option 1:**

You change the background-color of the .tweak-overlay-parallax-enabled .Parallax-item class like so:

```
.tweak-overlay-parallax-enabled .Parallax-item{
    background: none;
    background-color: #1d1f23;
}
```

**Option 2:**

You change the body background-color in the following class

```
.tweak-overlay-parallax-enabled.has-parallax-images:not(.tweak-site-width-option-constrained-width) {
    background-color: #1e2024 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, now i finally got rid of that annoying semi-transparent container.

Answer (score 1):

```
.Tweak-overlay-parallax-enabled.parallax-  item{
Background-color: #1d1f23;
}
```

You also need to change your div colour to the same as your background colour and set the border to 0px:

```
div{
Border: 0px, solid;
}
```

Also don’t use capital letters where I have because I’m typing this from my phone.

Thank you for your time